# Passing c# function as parameters to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Im trying to call a javascript function on a onclick method on a hyperlink, im also trying to pass a c# function as the parameters of the javascript function but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<a href='#' onclick='ShowTrack(<%#getTopHREF(Container.DataItem)%>); '>
```

Firebug tells me the following error: *missing exponent*

Comment: Are you expecting to run a server side function though the c# function reference being passed to Javascript?  If so it is not possible without using an AJAX call from ClientSide back to the ServerSide code.

Comment: I think it's possible. I've seen people calling javascript function with passing parameters of a c# function

Comment: I think most likely what you have seen is a call back to a URL or URI via AJAX that executes code on the serverside then returned back to the clientside.

Comment: Have you tried it with [<%= %>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(v=VS.100).aspx) tags instead? Your current code appears to be a data binding expression.

Comment: What you are trying to do does not work without Ajax. You may have seen other developers using the update panel with with ASP.NET controls but you will need to wrap your grid in an update panel.

Comment: s/he is just trying to insert a value into js server-side, not make an ajax call. And it can certainly be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this code is inside Template field of a DataControl in ASP.NET. You should reformat your code a little bit

```
<a href="#" onclick='<%# "ShowTrack('" + getTopHREF(Container.DataItem) + "');" %> '>
```

And in your code:

```
public string getTopHREF(object o) //Type object or the type of the items in your datasource 
{
//Do stuff
}
```